# React typescript typings not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

After installing via typings I get the below error in terminal

**Terminal error**

```
error TS2320: Interface 'Element' cannot simultaneously extend types 'ReactElement<any>' and 'ReactElement<any>'.
  Named property 'type' of types 'ReactElement<any>' and 'ReactElement<any>' are not identical.

ERROR in /Users/ajvivek/Dev/ES6/motionize-code/typings/globals/react/index.d.ts
(2375,5): error TS1036: Statements are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ERROR in /Users/ajvivek/Dev/ES6/motionize-code/typings/globals/react-dom/index.d.ts
(69,5): error TS2309: An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.

ERROR in /Users/ajvivek/Dev/ES6/motionize-code/node_modules/@types/react-dom/index.d.ts
(19,31): error TS2315: Type 'DOMAttributes' is not generic.

ERROR in /Users/ajvivek/Dev/ES6/motionize-code/node_modules/@types/react-dom/index.d.ts
(44,60): error TS2315: Type 'DOMAttributes' is not generic.

ERROR in /Users/ajvivek/Dev/ES6/motionize-code/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
(2368,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'a' must be of type 'HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>', but here has type 'HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>'.

ERROR in /Users/ajvivek/Dev/ES6/motionize-code/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
(2369,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'abbr' must be of type 'HTMLProps<HTMLElement>', but here has type 'HTMLProps<HTMLElement>'.
```

**index.d.ts**

`/// <reference path="globals/react/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/react-dom/index.d.ts" />`

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "files": [
    "./app/app.tsx",
    "./app/Hello.tsx",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I have followed the documentation provided in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Not sure what I have missed?

Is anyone facing this issue?

Comment: why you excluding   "typings/index.d.ts" ? this is the entry point of all the typings, also you don't need to specify the  files section, webpack will auto search the  .ts and .tsx in project directory and compile them

Comment: you can always use boilerplate's , just google react typescript boilerplate

Comment: Are you sure you followed the tutorial exactly? It doesn't use typings anymore, whereas your `tsconfig.json` seems to use one. While it's also implicit, it's intended to use TypeScript 2.0. (you also shouldn't need both a 'files' field and an 'exclude' field - one will be ignored).

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser was using typings earlier so stuck to it. typescript version is 2.0.3. I have removed the typescript file from exclude. still the same problem

Comment: @abhirathore2006 the intention was to build the boiler plate with some custom requirement using webpack

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser typings was preferred over tsd https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269 from the thread

Comment: @AjainVivek  do you have this repository over github so i can take a look ?

Comment: @abhirathore2006 git repo link https://github.com/ajainvivek/motionize

Comment: @AjainVivek ok, let me check that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured out the issue finally.

I went on to install types once via **tsd** and then **typings** that led to duplicate typings.

Deleted the **@types** folder to resolve my issue.

Comment: i have made some changes to make the project work properly, you can provide access to abhirathore2006@gmail.com /abhirathrore2006 so i can push the changes

Comment: @abhirathore2006 you can checkout dev branch and raise PR from your branch to dev. Any help appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: ok, however i checked your master branch, your implementation is quite different, i set it up for pure development and my webpack config also differs

Comment: I've deleted the types folder and got ` TS7026: JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists.`

Answer (score 12):

Just in case anyone else stumbles into this, I also got this error when there was a mismatch between my `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` packages. I ended up just deleting the `@types/react` entry in my `package.json` since it's automatically included by `@types/react-dom`.

Comment: Spot on Christopher Davies.  Resolved the issue for me!

Comment: this works for me using `"@types/react-dom": "15.5.1",`